# Database is not getting updated

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2012

The application flow I configured in my SSRS/DTSX file is not updating/inserting any record in database.

When I deploy same code on DEV and PRO, it working fine. But when I execute same code in ITG environment it not updating the database. **Connection managers** connectors are pointing to the correct database. **Configuration files dtsConfig** also holds the correct credentials. 
Am writing logs for each failure, there as well **no trace of DB connection or query failure**. I executed few queries on database to test the **permissions of the configured DB user**.

Unable to identify root case of why its not updating/inserting in ITG database. Is there anything am missing to validate.

Comment: "Connection managers connectors are pointing to the correct database."   Most likely case is that you are wrong about this.   Can you post screenshots that show how you investigated?

Comment: I configured and tested all the connections in all packages manually, resulted in Connection successful message.

Comment: And if your connections are deployed to the SSISDB as variables, (or .dtsconfig connection files) then that will be used and not the connections in the package. I would recommend some more testing as @TabAlleman suggested.

Comment: Am also tested it by executing BAT file through the command line admin, it takes dtsconfig there

Comment: Am thinking of pointing ITG  conn managers to DEV and see if ITG codebase is updating Dev db or not. That way I can isolate issue on db level or package level

Comment: So, what does SSRS have to do with this issue?  From the description and comments, SSRS appears to be a victim of the SSIS issue.

Comment: You can check the Connection Manager's **Expressions** to make sure that your don't have a **Connection String** property that is overriding the configuration.

Comment: @Brian that's correct, I am still trying to isolate this issue. Looking at database level.

Comment: @Hannover_Fist Now what I will be doing is that I will point my ITG packages to DEV database and see if it's updating DEV db or not. If it's updating or inserting records in dev db, it's means my ssis packages are working as expected. It then must be issue with ITG database

Comment: @Mangesh, is the ITG database truly the trading analytics database that I am thinking of, or does it have different meaning?